# Can i do decimal custom speeds in final cut pro?

Tags: video, video-editor, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

I want to speed a video up by a 102.4% in final cut pro, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...
Select the clip you want to speed up. Then hit Command-R (or “Modify” > “Retime” in the Menu bar) and the clip will get a green retime bar on top. Click in the little arrow down next to the percentage and choose “Custom” (or “Custom Speed” in the Menu bar).
Lastly enter your desired percentage or duration.

Comment: This method doesn't appear to allow decimal values.